# SASS Архитектура

Tags: css, sass, scss

Я хотел проявить для себя ясность. Я хочу понять архитектуру Sass проекта.
Нашел вот такую ссылочку: [7-1 Sass Architecture](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/user-interfaces/building-layouts-preprocessors/7-1-sass-architecture), а так же этот репозиторий: [KittyGiraudel / sass-boilerplate](https://github.com/KittyGiraudel/sass-boilerplate). Но полной ясности не стало.
Допустим возьмем те же `pages`, получается все стили сливаются в один файл, но что, если на другой странице вообще ничего общего нет с этими стилями, если все другое? Допустим по `/testfolder/` находится совершенно другой сайт. Как тогда быть?
Стоит ли `main.scss` вынести допустим в папку `home` и для `testfolder` создать тоже каталог и создать в нем тоже `main.scss`?
Или же для `testfolder` создать каталог в корне проекта и в него закинуть полностью свою папку sass?

А так же.. Правильно ли я понимаю, по сути все основные стили пишутся в `pages`?

В какой каталог правильнее было бы расположить стандартные стили для `scrollbar`?